# R: how to visualize the relationship between continuous and categorical data

Tags: r, visualization

I have the following `data.frame` which contains 3 categorical variables (different types of vascular pathology) and 1 continuous variable (Output). I'm interested in seeing the relationship between Output and the different types of vascular pathologies, i.e. is higher/lower output associated with mild/severe pathology?

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Vascular_Pathology_M = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Absent", "Mild", "Mild/Moderate", 
"Moderate/Severe", "Severe"), class = "factor"), Vascular_Pathology_F = structure(c(4L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Absent", "Mild", 
"Mild/Moderate", "Moderate/Severe", "Severe"), class = "factor"), 
    Vascular_Pathology_O = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Absent", "Mild", "Mild/Moderate", 
    "Moderate/Severe"), class = "factor"), Output = c(1.01789418758932, 
    1.05627630598801, 1.49233946102323, 1.38192374975672, 1.13097652937671, 
    0.861306979571144, 0.707820561413699, 1.16628243128399, 0.983163398006992, 
    1.23972603843843)), .Names = c("Vascular_Pathology_M", "Vascular_Pathology_F", 
"Vascular_Pathology_O", "Output"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L), class = "data.frame")
> df
   Vascular_Pathology_M Vascular_Pathology_F Vascular_Pathology_O    Output
1                Absent      Moderate/Severe               Absent 1.0178942
3                  Mild                 Mild        Mild/Moderate 1.0562763
4         Mild/Moderate               Absent      Moderate/Severe 1.4923395
5                Absent               Absent        Mild/Moderate 1.3819237
6                Absent               Absent               Absent 1.1309765
7                  Mild               Absent                 Mild 0.8613070
8       Moderate/Severe                 Mild               Absent 0.7078206
10        Mild/Moderate      Moderate/Severe               Absent 1.1662824
11               Absent               Absent               Absent 0.9831634
12                 Mild               Absent                 Mild 1.2397260
```

Comment: The question is very broad but that I can see it sounds like a statistical one.

Comment: [Boxplots](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_boxplot.html)? GGplot makes really nice [density plots](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_density.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the interaction of the various pathologies.  For example, with a barplot

```
## Make the interaction variable
df$interact <- interaction(df[, 1:3], sep="_")

## Look at means of groups
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(interact) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Output = mean(Output)) -> means

ggplot(means, aes(interact, Output))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(angle=90)) +
  xlab("Interaction")
```

[image]

or with points

```
ggplot(df, aes(interact, Output))+
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
  xlab("Interaction") +
  geom_point(data=means, col="red") +
  ylim(0, 1.6)
```

[image]

Comment: This kind of implies a series along the x axis though, and the data as presented aren't in series (e.g. point 1 to 2 gets pareto more severe, but that isn't true of the move from to point 2 to 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply plot the output against the categorical variables

```
plot(df[, 1], df[, 4])
plot(df[, 2], df[, 4])
plot(df[, 3], df[, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a 4 dimensional dataset. One option is to do a scatter plot (x/y = two dimensions), in a small multiple series (there's one more dimension), and map the Output variable to something visual like size (there's a fourth dimension).

Example, after putting your data in a `data.frame` called `my_dat` (since `df` is already assigned to a function in R). Points are jittered to show the multiple observations per point, and colored by Y position to help make clear which point goes with which category.

```
library(ggplot2)

my_dat$O_with_labels <- 
  factor(my_dat[, 3], labels=paste('Vasc Path O:', levels(my_dat[, 3])))

ggplot(my_dat, 
       aes(x=Vascular_Pathology_M, y=Vascular_Pathology_F)) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(size=Output, color=Vascular_Pathology_F)) + 
  facet_wrap(~O_with_labels) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))
```

[image]